Invalid hook call - Zustand in React (Typscript) using Inversify
I want to use Zustand as state management in my React app. I use Inversify as a dependency injection framework.
Unfortunately, all the examples I have found so far are without a dependency injection framework. In my implementation, I get the following error:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:77701:13)
    at useRef (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:97083:25)
    at useSyncExternalStoreWithSelector (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:100049:21)
    at useStore (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:111595:17)
    at RestaurantStore.useBoundStore [as useCounterStore] (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:111604:51)
    at ManageRestaurant.searchRestaurant (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:497:26)
    at async onInputChange (http://localhost:4040/static/js/bundle.js:3879:5)

How can I implement Zustand using Inversify in React Typescript?
store.ts
interface CounterState {
  count: number;
  increment: () => void;
  decrement: () => void;
}

@injectable()
export class Store {
  public useCounterStore = create<CounterState>((set) => ({
    count: 0,
    increment: () => {
      console.debug("Test.");
      set((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 }));
    },
    decrement: () => set((state) => ({ count: state.count - 1 })),
  }));
}

service.ts
@injectable()
export class Service {
  private store = useInjection(Store);

  public async run() {
    this.store.useCounterStore().increment()
    const count = this.store.useCounterStore().count
    console.log(count)
  }
}

dropdown.tsx
export const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const service = useInjection(Service);

  const data = {
    test: [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
    ],
  };

  const onInputChange = async () => {
    await service.run()
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      size="md"
      options={data.test}
      onInputChange={(event, value) => onInputChange(value)}
    />
  );
};


I am able to run the code without error using getState().
@injectable()
export class Service {
  private store = useInjection(Store);

  public async run() {
    const count1 = this.store.useCounterStore.getState().count
    console.log(count1)
    this.store.useCounterStore.getState().increment()
    const count2 = this.store.useCounterStore.getState().count
    console.log(count2)
  }
}

